# react-native how to customize android elevation shadow

Tags: react-native

Using android-specific style rule, `elevation`, I get a nasty "halo" effect when using. for example, this image shows `elevation: 20`:

[image: bigger "halo" effect]

Even a small elevation 1,2, or 3 gives the appearance that the element is "haloed"/has a border (bad)

[image: smaller "halo" effect]

How can I add more customization to the android-specific shadow to get rid of halo effect. iOS has specific rules like `shadowOpactiy`, `shadowRadius`, `shadowOffset`–but I don't see anything for android.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation there is no such thing as shadowopacity or any way to change the default shadow since is there 
by design, by "material design"
Source: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping

But what you can do is to use a component with a dummy view that has the desired border and then just use it in your render function like

```
render(){
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Viewwithborder>
     //pass the item you want to have custom elevation here
    </Viewwithborder>
  </View>
}
```

and in your custom "viewwithborder" you just do this

```
   render(){
   <View style={{styles.CustomElevationStyle}}>
      {this.props.children}
   </View> 
}
```